# Google Chrome XHR Preview Tab background grays out

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

Here are the screenshots of two network calls to GitHub API.

[image: Preview Panel with grayed out background]

[image: Usual and expected Preview Panel]

Why is one grayed out and not the other? Is this because of the Link Header which is supposed to be used for pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is because the response of the first one is too large. Applying syntax highlighting could freeze the UI.

By the way on the screeshot we can see the first response has a 'total_count' of 938 results, while the second one has only 12 results.

Comment: Yes, it has 938 results but only 100 of them are included in this response. The results are paginated. I'm seeing this for the first time, wondering why can't Chrome handle 100 fields in response.

Comment: There are instances where I saw the ajax success callback in triggered before the response loads but after the XHR is success. The success callback would read the response to be null and continue but later when the response is opened from preview it grays out with 938 results. Do you think of any reason for this?